# How to access WiFi camera stream in HTML5?

Tags: html, camera, wifi

Is it possible to access WiFi cameras using HTML5's **navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()**?

If not, what's the best way to stream feeds from these cameras in an HTML5 environment?